# I faced some problems. my code shows some error

Tags: php, laravel-5

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column >'category_description' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `tbl_category` (`category_id`, `category_name`, `category_description`, `publication_status`) >values (, sdfsf, , 1))

Comment: Just could make `category_description` column nullable, otherwise you must provide a value

Comment: already category_description column is not nullable. But same problems

Answer (score 1):

Your `category_description` cannot be null, update that column to `"Allow NULL"` or assign a value for that column.

Answer (score 0):

Your insert query is showing that you are not passing required values i.e.

```
insert into `tbl_category` (`category_id`, `category_name`, `category_description`, `publication_status`) >values (, sdfsf, , 1)
```

Assign a value to `category_description` or change the default value to 'NULL' in DB for that column.

Comment: That's good. What was the issue? Accept any answer which helped.